# Recovering removed packages in anaconda

Tags: python, conda

I wanted to remove a specific package, and mistakenly used `conda remove [package-name]`. Now, it seems that some of my packages have been removed. Also, I am not able to launch (even install Spyder editor). I wanted to ask if there is a way for recovering everything that has been deleted? I tried the following:

```
conda update spyder
spyder --reset
```

Also, I tried to install the spyder from Anaconda user-interface. However, I get error.

**UPDATE:** I tried `conda install --revision 10` to get back to the previous version, but it says that the following packages are missing:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: @Capybara Thank you for your reply. I had used conda remove gdal or resterio.  I removed it using Anaconda prompt and from base. Regarding the error I used the Anaconda user interface it only says "Multiple Errors Encountered" it has option "learn more" which directs to this https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#unsatisfiable

Comment: @Capybara Thanks. If I reinstall conda, whether the packages already installed will be deleted?

Comment: @Capybara Thank you. I tried that using the version that I want. It says:
[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y280o8h1kmg7j3/error.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda tracks "revisions" of all environments. Check them with

```bash
conda list --revisions
```

You'll see numbers there and can rollback to the `i-th` one with:

```bash
conda install --revision i
```

Given the error reported, you may need to add the **conda-forge** channel:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge --revision 10
```

Or, consider adding Conda Forge to your configuration:

```bash
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install --revision 10
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that using the version that I want. It says:
[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y280o8h1kmg7j3/error.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: @Carol please add info to the question by editing. I'm not going to click off-site, and it is relevant info. Comments are great for pinging other users or asking for clarification about comments. For example, ping me once you've edited the question ;)

Comment: @merv Thank you very much for your help. The process asked that "The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel". I said yes. At the moment it seems that spyder tries to launch, but I get this error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'ParentMissingError' from 'astroid.exceptions' (C:\Users\Carol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astroid\exceptions.py)

Comment: everything seems fine, and spyder is back to its previous version. However, I get the above error when launching it.

Comment: @Carol sorry I should have paid closer attention. If you have Anaconda base, you usually don’t want **conda-forge** to be prioritized over **defaults**. I’d consider this a new problem, so create a new question with details.

Comment: @ Ok, I will post a new question. By the way when I `conda config --show channels` I have only default channel. Whether going to version 9 solves the problem?